# How to write array in Return *function to main function? Or Is that possible?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, return

I'm studying on c and i wrote 2 array in main function. After compare them and sum their values in with in each array members. After find which one big than other and i printed which one is. It's okey until here. After i made another array and merge it in another function it's call - "int *mergeAndSort(....)" - I merged, sorted and printed in this function and returned it to main function. It's okey and work. But when i want to print third array in main function it's giving "Segmentation Fault".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *mergeAndSort(int a1[], int a2[], int as1, int as2);

int main()
{
    // Veri sayı limiti belirleme.
    int as1 = 0, as2 = 0;
    printf("\n1. dizi veri sayısı: ");
    scanf(" %d", &as1);
    printf("2. dizi veri sayısı: ");
    scanf(" %d", &as2);
    int a1[as1], a2[as2];
    int top1 = 0, top2 = 0;

    // Dizi elemanları girişi.
    printf("\n\t 1. Dizi Elemanları\n------------------------------------------------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < as1; i++) {
        printf(" -> %d. veri: ", i+1);
        scanf(" %d", &a1[i]);
        top1 += a1[i];
    }
    printf("\n\t 2. Dizi Elemanları\n------------------------------------------------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < as2; i++) {
        printf(" -> %d. veri: ", i+1);
        scanf(" %d", &a2[i]);
        top2 += a2[i];
    }

    // Dizi toplamlarını kıyaslama.
    if (top2 < top1)
        printf("\n1. dizi toplamı 2. dizi toplamından büyüktür.\n");
    else if (top2 > top1)
        printf("\n2. dizi toplamı 1. dizi toplamından büyüktür.\n");
    else 
        printf("\nDizilerin elemanları toplamı birbirine eşit!\n");
    
    int *a3 = sortAndRet(a1, a2, as1, as2);

    return 0;
}
int *mergeAndSort(int a1[], int a2[], int as1, int as2)
{
    // Diziler birleşitirildi.
    int as3 = as1 + as2;
    int a3[as3];
    for (int i = 0; i < as3; i++){
        if (i >= as1)
            a3[i] = a2[i-as1];
        else
            a3[i] = a1[i];
    }

    // Birleşmiş dizi "Küçükten Büyüğe" sıralandı.
    printf("\nBirleşen dizi \"Küçükten Büyüğe\" sıralandı:\n-------------------------------------------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < as3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < as3; j++) {
            if (a3[i] < a3[j]) {
                int tmp = a3[i];
                a3[i] = a3[j];
                a3[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf(" -> ");
    for (int i = 0; i < as3; i++)
        printf("%d ", a3[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return a3;
}
```

I can returned it's address but cannot wrote in main function when i tried. Why is that? Is it not possible? Am i misunderstood pointers? (Sorry 'bout my English, it's not very well.)

I'm expecting to write the returned *array values in main function. If it's can not possible than i want to learn why is that.

Comment: If you're studying C, doesn't your textbook explain that you can't return an array from a function?

Comment: I don't have textbook. I'm bookless! -_-

Comment: Whatever material you're learning from -- teachers, tutorials, etc. should all cover this.

Comment: Okey. So that means i can return only one data then. I can display it but i can not merge with return.

Comment: The common way to have multiple outputs is to take pointer parameters. You can also return a struct.

Comment: Thanks for help. I'll keep in my mind.